# Nested divs from object javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, object

I have an object:

```
var data = {
    "lay": "h_m_f",
    "h": {
        "par": {
            "first_second": {
                "first": {
                    "module": {
                        "article": {
                            "archivclankyrubrika": "3",
                            "pocetclanku": "10"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "second": {
                }
            }
        },
        "next": {
            "one": {
                "val": {
                }
            },
        }
    },
}
};
```

I try to build html nested divs from this object. And if node doesn't has children then show inner text. But problem is that this script doesn't loop through children. In result I have only 2 divs.
 Where is my problem guys? Thanks for answer. This is my script:

```
function create_node(obj){
    var node = document.createElement('div');
    node.setAttribute('class', Object.keys(obj)[0]);
    for (var i in obj) {
        node.appendChild(create_node(obj.i));
    }
    return node;
}
console.log(create_node(jsonTemplate));
```

Update: ideal result for me: every object is div with class before module. Module is the last div and cihldren's key of module show as a text.

```
<div class="h">
    <div class="par">
        <div class='first_second'>
            <div class="first">
                 <div class="module">
                     article
                 </div>
            </div>
            <div class="second">
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="next">
         <div class="one">
             <div class="val">
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `obj.i` is not correct, it should be `obj[i]`

Comment: What should the HTML look like?

Comment: @SergeK, it make infinite loop.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan like `<div class="h"><div class="first_second"><div class="module">article</div></div></div>`

Comment: Then what happens with `par` and `first`, `archivclankyrubrika`, `3`?

Comment: @trincot ideal for me, that every key in object -  div with  class = key name. But 'article' its a text in div class="module".

Comment: How can we know from the object structure that `article` should be a text, and then what happens with `archivclankyrubrika`, `3`? Just edit your question and provide the complete expected HTML for the object you have provided. Don't leave us guessing.

Comment: @trincot Im sorry. I updated question.

Comment: I don't understand the logic. Why do you want a tag for `second` but not for `next` or anything below it? There are several keys and values in the object that apparently have no relation to the output? What is the logic?

Comment: @trincot I showed piece of html result and write and below... So, now i edited and show all html for this object. Sorry, again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a node is an object - iterate the children and append the results, if it's not - append the text:

```js
var jsonTemplate = {"lay":"h_m_f","h":{"par":{"first_second":{"first":{"module":{"article":{"archivclankyrubrika":"3","pocetclanku":"10"}}},"second":{}}},"next":{"one":{"val":{}}}}};

function create_node(value, key){
    var node = document.createElement('div');
    node.setAttribute('class', key || '');
    
    if(key === 'module') {
      Object.keys(value).forEach(function(key) {
        node.appendChild(document.createTextNode(key || ''));
      })
      return node;
    }
    
    if(value && typeof value === 'object') {     
      for (var i in value) {
        node.appendChild(create_node(value[i], i));
      }
    }
    
    return node;
}

root.appendChild(create_node(jsonTemplate));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Be aware that `null` is an `'object'`, too.

Comment: @OriDrori Thank you, sir! I have a question. If I change key "second" to "first". That means now I have 2 keys "first". Why in result shows just one of them - last?

Comment: Object property names should be unique. If you've got two properties with the same name. The 2nd one will override the 1st one. So you've actually got only 1 "first" in the object

Comment: @OriDrori Can I ask you. is it possible to do it in reverse. I mean from html build object? Thank you